# How to set a manual filter on Google Custom Search Engine (free version)

Tags: html, search, search-engine, google-search, code-search-engine

How can I set a manual filter on Google Custom Search Engine (not from CSE panel)?

For example, to open the link in a new tab I'm using this code:

```
<gcse:searchresults-only linktarget="_blank"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Now I want to set the "safe mode", and also set the results per page (to show 10 results, for instance).

To be clearer, I want to allow users to change those filters from my website, that's is why I'm trying to add them manually! Thanks.

Comment: could you add the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Assuming the `SafeSearch="off"` attribute is appended to the above element, what are the conditions that the toggle should be based on to change between the values `on` and `off`?

Comment: active & off is and moderate i think, but i want just `active` and `off`, checkbox checked set `SafeSearch="active"` checkbox unchecked `SafeSearch="off"`  https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element

Comment: Use both `webSearchSafesearch` and `SafeSearch`  to be `"active"` or `off` where you can change both.