# How do I edit PHP variable with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, cookies

I want to update a PHP variable `$LinkOpen` based on the current state of a checkbox element `.avflipswitch`.

Based on the `.avflipswitch` checkbox state, I want to toggle the value of my PHP variable `$LinkOpen` between `'_blank'` and `'_self'` so I can push that value to my *Google CSE* link target attribute.

---

What I have tried so far:

```
 $('.avflipswitch').on("change", function (e){ 
   if(this.checked){
     functionOne(<?php $LinkOpen = '_blank';?>);
   }
   else{
     functionTwo(<?php $LinkOpen = '_self';?>);
   }
});

<gcse:searchresults-only linktarget="<?php echo $LinkOpen;?>"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Comment: PHP runs before JavaScript code, so not sure what you expect to happen.

Comment: so is not possible? :|

Comment: `<?php $LinkOpen = '_self';?>` this is assignment, `$LinkOpen ` now equals `_self`  (well when the server does it's thing) as noted JS runs at a different time, and place even.

Comment: can this be done only with PHP?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There are different solutions based on what you are doing.

Comment: It can be done with only PHP but you would need to do a page refresh. If you're looking to do it with JS + PHP you'd need some sort of Ajax mechanism to trigger the PHP code from JS.

Comment: I just edit my question now, so i want to allow user to change Google cse link open _self or _blank

Comment: It is called AJAX...... - loads of help on SO about that.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just push the value to a cookie using **JavaScript** or **jQuery** and then let **PHP** retrieve the value from that cookie like this:

### JavaScript + PHP:

```js
/* JavaScript */
const switch = document.querySelector(".avflipswitch")[0];
    
switch.addEventListener("change", function(){
  let blankTar = "_blank";
  let selfTar = "_self";
      
  if(this.checked){
    document.cookie = "target =" + blankTar;
    window.location.reload();
  }
  else{
    document.cookie = "target =" + selfTar;
    window.location.reload();
  }
}

/* PHP */

<gcse:searchresults-only linktarget="<?php echo $_COOKIE['target']; ?>"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

### jQuery + PHP:

```js
/* jQuery */

$('.avflipswitch').on("change", function (){
  let blankTar = "_blank";
  let selfTar = "_self";

  if(this.checked){
    document.cookie = "target =" + blankTar;
    window.location.reload();
  }
  else{
    document.cookie = "target =" + selfTar;
    window.location.reload();
  }
});

/* PHP */

<gcse:searchresults-only linktarget="<?php echo $_COOKIE['target']; ?>"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Comment: Yes thanks again,  your code works perffect, can you give to me a suggestion, how I can add and safesearch button,  off and active?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Leo. safesearch button?

Comment: same thing like this, but no _blank/_self, i want to do off/active example if checked SafeSearch="active" if unchecked SafeSearch="off"

Comment: Oh ok. So you want to add this toggle attribute to an HTML element or something?

Comment: with checkbox to allow user to change the search angine  SafeSearch="active"  SafeSearch=="off" so on change I want to change active to off, or off to active, but that is diferent, if I don't find solution I ask again new question, thanks again for your help.

Comment: if you have time please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078071/how-set-filter-manually-on-google-custom-search-engine-free-version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186569/discussion-between-andrewl-and-leo).

Comment: Hello again! is possible, to do this function only with js or php?

Comment: on first page load do not have any function so  linktarget is empty, I need to checkbox, after that start the fnction, and when i change the query example from web, to video still the  linktarget is empty so i need to uncheck and check again, after that start working! can you help me to fix this please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean Leo. So you want the checkbox to be checked every time a page load? Or?

Comment: if I set it` _blank` from this url example: `https://example.com/search/?q=blablabla` that works but when I change it `https://example.com/news/search/?q=blablabla` that is not working so I need to turn off on again to get `_blank`

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying is not possible in php, but very easy with jquery:

```
$('.avflipswitch').on("change", function (e){ 
    if(this.checked){
     $('a').attr("target","_self")
    }
    else{
     $('a').attr("target","_blank")
    }
});
```